# get HTTP status code with MeteorJS

Tags: node.js, http, meteor, prerender

Do you know if i can get the HTTP status code with MeteorJS (or directly with NodeJS) ? I've read on [HTTP Api](https://docs.meteor.com/api/http.html) documentation, but no result :(

For setting my routes, i use [Iron Router](https://github.com/iron-meteor/iron-router).

I woud like get my page status code for add prerender balise :

```
<meta name="prerender-status-code" content="404">
```

I use MeteorJS on latest version :)

Thank you community !

Answer (score 1):

You can try using:`Iron.Location.get().path;` To get current link. And use the solution by Andre to find the status code.

Answer (score 0):

From the docs, the callback passed to HTTP.call will be called with 2 parameters: error, result.
Result is an object with the statusCode property, which is a number if the request succeeded, null on error.

> When run in asynchronous mode, the callback receives two arguments, error and result. The error argument will contain an Error if the request fails in any way, including a network error, time-out, or an HTTP status code in the 400 or 500 range. In case of a 4xx/5xx HTTP status code, the response property on error matches the contents of the result object. When run in synchronous mode, either result is returned from the function, or error is thrown.
>
> Contents of the result object:
>
> statusCode Number
>
> Numeric HTTP result status code, or null on error.

Example code from the docs:

```
HTTP.call('POST', 'http://api.twitter.com/xyz', {
    data: { some: 'json', stuff: 1 }
}, () => (error, result) {
    if (!error) {
        console.log(result.statusCode);
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi. Yes, but it's external URL. I want see the status code off my current page :)

Answer (score 0):

To be able to tell prerender that your page or data was not found you have to add the following code to your page header.

```
<meta name="prerender-status-code" content="404">
```

I use https://github.com/kadirahq/meteor-dochead for that.

```
Router.route('my-route', {
    path: ['/my-route/:param1'],
    waitOn: function () {
        return [
            Meteor.subscribe('myCollection', this.params.param1)
        ];
    },
    data: function () {
        var data  =   myCollection.findOne({});

        if (this.ready() && !data) {
            var metaInfo = {name: "prerender-status-code", content: "404"};
            DocHead.addMeta(metaInfo);
        }

        return {
            routerData: {
                data: data
            }
        }
    }
});
```

You can also set it on your default PageNotFound template:

```
Template.PageNotFound.rendered = function() {
    var metaInfo = {name: "prerender-status-code", content: "404"};
    DocHead.addMeta(metaInfo);
});
```